# how should i architect aws lambda to support parallel process in batch model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i have an aws lambda function to do some statistics on over 1k of stock tickers after market close. i have an option like below.

- setup a cron job in ec2 instance and trigger a cron job to submit 1k http request asyn (e.g. http://xxxxx.lambdafunction.xxxx?ticker= to trigger the aws lambda function (or submit 1k request to SNS and let lambda to pickup.

i think it should run fine, but much appreciate if there is any serverless/PaaS approach to trigger task

Comment: A better approach might be to put your tasks into an SQS-queue and use that queue as event trigger for your Lambda function.

Comment: thanks for the info. if using SQS-queue as event trigger my function, how can i know all of my 1k tickets finish before my next step of batch job? I wonder if i need to write a separate process to monitor status for those 1k lambda jobs

Comment: You could have a look at AWS Step Functions and if they fit your need for that.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

On top of my head, Here are a couple of ways to achieve what you need:

---

**Option 1:** [Cost-Effective]

1. Post all the ticks to [AWS FIFO SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html).
2. Define [triggers on this queue to invoke lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html).

*`Result`*: Since you are posting all the events in FIFO queue that maintains the order, all the events will be polled sequentially. More-over SQS to lambda trigger will help you scale automatically based on the number of message in the queue.

---

**Option 2:** [Costly and can easily scale for real-time processing]

1. Same as above, but instead of posting to FIFO queue, [post to Kinesis Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html).
2. Enable [Kinesis stream to trigger lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html).

*`Result`*: Kinesis will ensure the order of event arriving in the stream and lambda function invocation will be invoked based on the number of shards in the stream. This implementation scales significantly. If you have any future use-case for real-time processing of tickers, this could be a great solution.

---

**Option 3:** [Cost Effective, alternate to Option:1]

1. Collect all ticker events(1k or whatever) and put it into a file.
2. Upload this file to [AWS S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpREST.html).
3. Enable [S3 event notification to trigger proxy lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html).
4. This proxy lambda function reads the s3 file and based on the total number of events in the file, it will spawn **n** parallel actor lambda function.
5. Actor lambda function will process each event.

*`Result`*: Easy to implement, cost-effective and provides easy scaling based on your custom algorithm to distribute the load in the proxy lambda function.

---

**Option 4:** [All-serverless]

1. Write a lambda function that gets the list of tickers from some web-server.
2. Define an [AWS cloud watch rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) for generating events based on [cron/frequency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).
3. Add a trigger to this [cloudwatch rule to invoke proxy lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).
4. Proxy lambda function will use any combination of above options[1, 2 or 3] to trigger the actor lambda function for processing the records.

*`Result`*: Everything can be configured via AWS console and easy to use. Alternatively, you can also write your [AWS cloud formation template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-guide.html) to generate all the required resources in a single go.

---

Having said that, now I will leave this up to you to choose the right solution based on your business/cost requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda fanout option.

You can follow these steps to process 1k or more using serverless aproach.

```
1.Store all the stock tickers in a S3 file. 
2.Create a master lambda which will read the s3 file and split the stocks in groups of 10. 
3. Create a child lambda which will make the async call to external http service and fetch the details. 
4. In the master lambda Loop through these groups and invoke 100 child lambdas passing in each group and return the results to the
Master lambda
5. Collect all the information returned from the child lambdas and continue with your processing here.
```

Now you can trigger this master lambda at the end of markets everyday using CloudWatch time based rule scheduler.

This is a complete serverless approach.